# Why does the material show black in preview?

Tags: texturing, materials, blender-internal-render-engine

I created a scene and imported an fbx object, but the material shows as black. I  expected the materials not to be imported correctly, so I tried to add again the right png diffuse texture, but for some reason it still shows as black even in the material preview, which I don't think is normal.

Here are the relevant files:

[.blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/38392)

[fbx and textures](http://opengameart.org/sites/default/files/Lamppost_0.zip)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The material shows up as black in render because it has the *Reflectivity* factor set to *1.000*, which means it reflects the world (which is set to very dark color) in 100%.
[image]

Try to decrease the *Reflectivity* of the material.
[image]

The object displays no textures, because the file has no packed files (image textures) within. Add your own texture using a *Texture* panel.
[image]